# Displaying/ calling dynamic form field data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic

I'm new here so apologies for any etiquet fails.

I have a form with a dynamically generated field name made up of the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $eCart1->DisplayInfo("ID"); ?>" name="eCart1_Delete_<?php echo $eCart1->DisplayIndex; ?>" />
```

I then wish to use this posted variable to delete records from a table using the following code:

```
// Phils remove from stored cart START //
while (!$eCart1->EOF()) {
$deletedID = $eCart1->DisplayIndex;
mysql_select_db($database_connEcommerce, $connEcommerce);
$query_itemQ = "DELETE FROM ecom_basket WHERE OptionID =     ".$_POST['eCart1_Delete_$deletedID']."";
$itemQ = mysql_query($query_itemQ, $connEcommerce) or  die(mysql_error());
$eCart1->MoveNext();
}
$eCart1->MoveFirst();
// Phils remove from stored cart END //
```

My problem is that when I run the script the PHP syntax is fine however MySQL throws a syntax error.

Do you need any more info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are your optionIDs integers? Also... use mysqli, not mysql.

Comment: Concerning more info: how about the syntax error?

Comment: Sorry, the syntax error is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Yes OptionIDs are integers

Answer (score 0):

are you sure this:
$_POST['eCart1_Delete_$deletedID']

Should not be
$_POST['eCart1_Delete_' . $deletedID]

Your SQL would likely fail if your OptionID is blank

Comment: Unfortunately that still throws the MYSQL syntax error. Also if I try to echo the field it doesn't render.

Answer (score 0):

add:

echo $query_itemQ to your code after the $query_itemQ = .....

This will tell you exactly what your SQL statement is sending to your database.  You can then use that statement in phpmyadmin to see if it works there.   If it works in phpmyadmin, then it is a connection issue.  If it gives the same error in phpmyadmin, then post your sql statement here (from the echo) and we can look at it again.

Comment: If that is not rendering then either you did not put it directly after defining the statement or you have a different issue.   At the point I asked you to echo the statement, it has not even tried to use the statement so you wouldn't be getting to a point where it could fail executing the statement.  This should be: $query_itemQ = "DELETE FROM ecom_basket WHERE OptionID =     ".$_POST['eCart1_Delete_$deletedID']."";
echo $query_itemQ . "<br />"; (so each statement created during the while loop would write to screen)